# Delphi FileSetDate is erroneous

Tags: delphi, filesystems, delphi-xe8

I want to modify the updated date of a file. So I use the following code to do it.

```
procedure FileDateUpdate;
var
  date1,date2 : TDateTime;
  file1, file2 : string;
begin
  file1 := 'G:\ab.pdf';
  file2 := 'G:\Shirish\ab.pdf';
  FileAge( file1, date1);
  FileSetDate( file2, DateTimeToFileDate(date1) );
  Fileage( file2, date2);
  ShowMessage('File1 date: '+ DateTimeToStr(date1) + '|| File2 date: '+ DateTimeToStr(date2));
end;
```

Output

```
File1 date: 24-05-2016 11:34:35|| File2 date: 24-05-2016 11:34:34
```

Interestingly the dates are never the same on both the files.

If I use the deprecated method `FileAge` it works fine

```
i := FileAge(file1);
FileSetDate(file2, i);
j := FileAge(file2);
ShowMessage('File1 date: '+ DateTimeToStr(FileDateToDateTime(i)) + '|| File2 date: '+ DateTimeToStr(FileDateToDateTime(j)));
```

Output

`File1 date: 24-05-2016 11:34:36|| File2 date: 24-05-2016 11:34:36`

Comment: If the files are on FAT32 filesystem that can be the problem. If they are then try it on NTFS.

Comment: I don't have Delphi XE8 installed on any of my machines now so I tested this in Delphi Seattle and Delphi Berlin and in both your code works OK fro both NTFS and FAT32 partitions. But there is on fata flow in your code. You are not checking the return values of used methods and therefore you can't be sure if all of them succeeded. A assume that your program might fail to update the last update information of your second file because it might still be opened by some program at the time.

Comment: Also, MSDN says: "*Not all file systems can record creation and last access times and not all file systems record them in the same manner. For example, on FAT, create time has a resolution of 10 milliseconds, **write time has a resolution of 2 seconds**, and access time has a resolution of 1 day (really, the access date). **Therefore, the `GetFileTime` function may not return the same file time information set using `SetFileTime`**. NTFS delays updates to the last access time for a file by up to one hour after the last access.*"

Comment: I am using NTFS, but application may run across different FileSystem

Answer (score 1):

Over time I have collected some functions in some units from www.
(I do not remember if I've changed some of them).

Perhaps this could be of help to chance
(I used this for change the "Puvananthiran delphi notepad" 
 for updated the file loaded according to the last modification date).`

```
unit FileTimeUtils;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

function DateTimeToFileTime(const aDt: TDateTime): TFileTime;
function FileTimeToDateTime(ft: TFileTime): TDateTime;

procedure DaDateTimeToFileTime(const aDt: TDateTime; var aFileTime: TFileTime);
procedure DaFileTimeToDateTime(ft: TFileTime; var aDateTime: TDateTime);

function FindLastWrittenFile(const aDir, aSearch: String): String;
function GetFileDateTime(const aFileName: String; var aCreationTime, aLastAccessTime, aLastModificationTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
function SetFileDateTime(const aFileName: String; aNewCreationTime, aNewAccessTime, aNewModifyTime: TDateTime): Boolean;

function GetCreationTime(const aFileName: String): TDateTime;
function GetLastAccessTime(const aFileName: String): TDateTime;
function GetLastWriteTime(const aFileName: String): TDateTime;

function SetCreationTime(const aFileName: String; aNewCreationTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
function SetLastAccessTime(const aFileName: String; aNewAccessTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
function SetLastWriteTime(const aFileName: String; aNewModifyTime: TDateTime): Boolean;

implementation


function DateTimeToFileTime(const aDt: TDateTime): TFileTime;
var
  st: TSystemTime;
begin
  DateTimeToSystemTime(aDt, st);
  if not (SystemTimeToFileTime(st, Result) and LocalFileTimeToFileTime(Result, Result)) then
    RaiseLastOSError
end;


function FileTimeToDateTime(ft: TFileTime): TDateTime;
var
  st: TSystemTime;
begin
  if not (FileTimeToLocalFileTime(ft, ft) and FileTimeToSystemTime(ft, st)) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Result:= SystemTimeToDateTime(st)
end;


procedure DaDateTimeToFileTime(const aDt: TDateTime; var aFileTime: TFileTime);
begin
  aFileTime:= DateTimeToFileTime(aDt)
end;


procedure DaFileTimeToDateTime(ft: TFileTime; var aDateTime: TDateTime);
begin
  aDateTime:= FileTimeToDateTime(ft)
end;


function FindLastWrittenFile(const aDir, aSearch: String): String;
var
  Dir: String;
  vR:  TSearchRec;
  LastWrite, LastWriteAllFiles: TDateTime;
begin
  {$Warnings Off}
  Dir:= IncludeTrailingBackslash(aDir);
  LastWriteAllFiles:= 0;
  Result:= '';
  if FindFirst(Dir + aSearch, faAnyFile - faDirectory, vR) = 0 then
    repeat
      LastWrite:= FileTimeToDateTime(vR.FindData.ftLastWriteTime);
      {$Warnings On}
      if LastWrite > LastWriteAllFiles then
      begin
        LastWriteAllFiles:= LastWrite;
        Result:= vR.Name
      end
    until FindNext(vR) <> 0;
  SysUtils.FindClose(vR)
end;


function GetFileDateTime(const aFileName: String; var aCreationTime, aLastAccessTime, aLastModificationTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
  FileHandle: Cardinal;
  CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Result:= False;
  FileHandle:= CreateFile(PChar(aFileName), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if FileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    try
      Result:= GetFileTime(FileHandle, @CreationTime, @LastAccessTime, @LastWriteTime);
      DaFileTimeToDateTime(CreationTime, aCreationTime);
      DaFileTimeToDateTime(LastAccessTime, aLastAccessTime);
      DaFileTimeToDateTime(LastWriteTime, aLastModificationTime)
    finally
      CloseHandle(FileHandle)
    end
end; { GetFileDateTime }


function SetFileDateTime(const aFileName: String; aNewCreationTime, aNewAccessTime, aNewModifyTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
  FileHandle: Cardinal;
  CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Result:= False;

  CreationTime := DateTimeToFileTime(aNewCreationTime);
  LastAccessTime:= DateTimeToFileTime(aNewAccessTime);
  LastWriteTime:= DateTimeToFileTime(aNewModifyTime);

  FileHandle:= FileOpen(aFileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareExclusive);
  try
    if SetFileTime(FileHandle, @CreationTime, @LastAccessTime, @LastWriteTime) then
      Result:= True
  finally
    FileClose(FileHandle)
  end
end; { SetFileDateTime }


function GetCreationTime(const aFileName: String): TDateTime;
var
  ffd: TWin32FindData;
  dft: DWord;
  LFT: TFileTime;
  h: THandle;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  h:= Windows.FindFirstFile(PChar(aFileName), ffd);
  if INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE <> h then
  begin
    Windows.FindClose(h);
    FileTimeToLocalFileTime(ffd.ftCreationTime, LFT);
    FileTimeToDosDateTime(LFT, LongRec(dft).Hi, LongRec(dft).Lo);
    Result:= FileDateToDateTime(dft)
  end
end;


{------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "GetLastAccessTime()" will return a given file's last access time
  as a Delphi "TDateTime" type which you can convert to a string by using the
  "DateTimeToStr()" function. For example:

  MessageDlg('c:config.sys was last accessed on ' +
    DateTimeToStr( GetLastAccessTime( 'c:config.sys' ) ),
    mtInformation, [mbOk], 0 );
------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function GetLastAccessTime(const aFileName: String): TDateTime;
var
  ffd: TWin32FindData;
  dft: DWord;
  LFT: TFileTime;
  h: THandle;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  // get file information
  h:= Windows.FindFirstFile(PChar(aFileName), ffd);
  if INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE <> h then
  begin

    // we're looking for just one file,
    // so close our "find"
    Windows.FindClose(h);

    // convert the FILETIME to
    // local FILETIME
    FileTimeToLocalFileTime(ffd.ftLastAccessTime, LFT);

    // convert FILETIME to
    // DOS time
    FileTimeToDosDateTime(LFT, LongRec(dft).Hi, LongRec(dft).Lo);

    // finally, convert DOS time to
    // TDateTime for use in Delphi's
    // native date/time functions
    Result:= FileDateToDateTime(dft)
  end
end;


function GetLastWriteTime(const aFileName: String): TDateTime;
var
  ffd: TWin32FindData;
  dft: DWord;
  LFT: TFileTime;
  h: THandle;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  h:= Windows.FindFirstFile(PChar(aFileName), ffd);
  if INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE <> h then
  begin
    Windows.FindClose(h);
    FileTimeToLocalFileTime(ffd.ftLastWriteTime, LFT);
    FileTimeToDosDateTime(LFT, LongRec(dft).Hi, LongRec(dft).Lo);
    Result:= FileDateToDateTime(dft)
  end
end;


function SetCreationTime(const aFileName: String; aNewCreationTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
  FileHandle: Cardinal;
  CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime: TDateTime;
  ftCreationTime, ftLastAccessTime, ftLastWriteTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Result:= False;
  if not GetFileDateTime(aFileName, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime) then
    Exit;

  ftCreationTime := DateTimeToFileTime(aNewCreationTime);
  ftLastAccessTime:= DateTimeToFileTime(LastAccessTime);
  ftLastWriteTime:= DateTimeToFileTime(LastWriteTime);

  FileHandle:= FileOpen(aFileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareExclusive);
  try
    if SetFileTime(FileHandle, @ftCreationTime, @ftLastAccessTime, @ftLastWriteTime) then
      Result:= True
  finally
    FileClose(FileHandle)
  end
end; { SetCreationTime }


function SetLastAccessTime(const aFileName: String; aNewAccessTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
  FileHandle: Cardinal;
  CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime: TDateTime;
  ftCreationTime, ftLastAccessTime, ftLastWriteTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Result:= False;
  if not GetFileDateTime(aFileName, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime) then
    Exit;

  ftCreationTime := DateTimeToFileTime(CreationTime);
  ftLastAccessTime:= DateTimeToFileTime(aNewAccessTime);
  ftLastWriteTime:= DateTimeToFileTime(LastWriteTime);

  FileHandle:= FileOpen(aFileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareExclusive);
  try
    if SetFileTime(FileHandle, @ftCreationTime, @ftLastAccessTime, @ftLastWriteTime) then
      Result:= True
  finally
    FileClose(FileHandle)
  end
end; { SetLastAccessTime }


function SetLastWriteTime(const aFileName: String; aNewModifyTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
  FileHandle: Cardinal;
  CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime: TDateTime;
  ftCreationTime, ftLastAccessTime, ftLastWriteTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Result:= False;
  if not GetFileDateTime(aFileName, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime) then
    Exit;

  ftCreationTime := DateTimeToFileTime(CreationTime);
  ftLastAccessTime:= DateTimeToFileTime(LastAccessTime);
  ftLastWriteTime:= DateTimeToFileTime(aNewModifyTime);

  FileHandle:= FileOpen(aFileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareExclusive);
  try
    if SetFileTime(FileHandle, @ftCreationTime, @ftLastAccessTime, @ftLastWriteTime) then
      Result:= True
  finally
    FileClose(FileHandle)
  end
end; { SetLastWriteTime }

end.
```

the usage is simple:

```
// For Test: Drag two files in executable program self

program FileDateUpdate;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, FileTimeUtils;

{$R *.res}

var
  FirstFile, UpdateFile, msg1, msg2: String;
  CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime: TDateTime;

begin
  FirstFile := ParamStr(1);
  UpdateFile:= ParamStr(2);

  msg1:= 'First file is  ' + FirstFile + '   -   Second file is  ' + UpdateFile;

  msg1:= msg1 + #13#10 + #13#10 + 'Note: The second file get the date of first file...';

  msg2:= ' Confirm ?';

  if MessageBox(0, Pchar(msg1), Pchar(msg2), MB_YESNO + MB_ICONQUESTION) = IDYES  then
  begin
    GetFileDateTime(FirstFile, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime);
    SetFileDateTime(UpdateFile, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime)
  end
end.
`
```

Comment: How does this answer the question about whether FileSetDate works properly or not?

Comment: It seems obvious. But I hope that someone has appreciated the effort to give an answer. If you work for some employer you can not tell that you don't know it does not work filesetdate. you have the urgency to give an alternative answer.  And after two days don't it seems that someone has responded for a solution that works with filesetdate or not. If I had been the author of the question and you the author of the answer you would have made me happy. I would have given +10. But not everyone knows to say thanks you and sorry.

Comment: The poster already had a workaround, and showed it in the post. The question was about the specific behavior of FileSetDate, which you have not addressed in your answer at all. Maybe some places it's appropriate to write an answer about cat food flavors when the question asks about the behavior of a specific breed of cat, but we're not that site. We answer the specific question first, and *then* if you have an alternative to suggest you can offer it. You've not answered the specific question yet.

Comment: You answered yourself: If the poster already had a workaround, and showed it in the post What prevents me show another, since no one else has answered the specific question yet ?
Perhaps because someone might not want a deprecated method and then a warning in compiler ? If you have a code that works: you lose your time in finding bugs in code written by others ? I no.

Comment: As I said, it's fine to offer an alternative **once you've addressed the original question**, and you **have not done so**. I don't need to debate this with you anyway. My comments were made as a courtesy.

Comment: Why breaking through a wall if you can get from next door ?
When I see the code written by others that does not work I put my hands in my hair. The question for me would be totally reversed.
In my opinion post like this they should not be allowed because 
what counts is the result, not as you get it. Who will be posted to decide what is best for him. A programmer is a creative not a machine that is forced to obscure bugs. With all due respect.

Comment: @PeterCrossTheRiver, Appreciate the work around, but I have to consider where and all we have used FielSetDate. I was hoping more of why is it varying. I do have a work around based similar to your solution

Comment: @Shirish11, Curiosity killed the cat. However become,
a method to satisfy your question subsist, but you think about it if it's be worth. If you had the source code of the function in question would be certainly more simple to do it, in the absence of what: "analysis behavioural", tell me you do and I'll tell you who you are.
In other words analyzing a log file with the input and output variables 
in a set reasonable and restricted you can understand and identify the algorithm that be to the base. In these conditions, does not exist an easier method. Good luck, if you do.